# Would the Life cleric's Disciple of Life feature supercharge the Regenerate spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, healing

Reading through the cleric spell list, it occurred to me that if the Life Domain cleric's Disciple of Life feature works on the *regenerate* spell, you would regain 10 hp instead of 1.

Is this valid?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### This combination works

The [Life Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LifeDomain)'s [Disciple of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DiscipleofLife-131) feature states:

> Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell’s level.

Note that this not say once per spell or once per cast or similar wording, this bonus to healing occurs each time you are using a spell to restore hit points.

The [*regenerate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/regenerate) spell description states:

> For the duration of the spell, the target regains 1 hit point at the start of each of its turns (10 hit points each minute).

Since *regenerate* restores hit points at the start of the creature's turn, this means you are using a spell to restore health each time at the start of the creature's turn so this does change to 10 hit points each time. (Assuming you cast it using a 7th-level slot.)

There is a [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=15) question that is similar to this, about the *goodberry* spell which also provides several instances of healing:

> **If I’m a cleric/druid with the Disciple of Life feature, does the *goodberry* spell benefit from the feature?**
>
> Yes. The Disciple of Life feature would make each berry restore 4 hit points, instead of 1, assuming you cast *goodberry* with a 1st-level spell slot.